# Xcode Failed to create provisioning profile

Tags: ios, xcode, provisioning-profile

I am new to Xcode and ran into an error. I am trying to sign my app to deploy it to the App Store. But I get this error:

[image: Error]

I already searched in forums but none of this solutions worked.

Comment: remove the automatically manage signing

Comment: I found out the solution by myself. I had to add developer certificates to my apple developer account. Now everything works just fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this:

1. creating new `provisioning profile` from you developer account
2. Unchecking Automatically manage signing. in xcode
3. Select the new `provisioning profile` you created in step 1.

I had the same error, after hours I fixed folling the steps above.